# Find a basis of the vector subspace $\{A\in M_{2\times2}(K)\mid\operatorname{tr}A=0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find a basis of the following vector subspace: $W=\{A\in M_{2\times2}(K)\mid\operatorname{tr}A=0\}$.

I know I should make a matrix like for example: $\begin {pmatrix}a& b \\ c& -a \end{pmatrix}$ and it's pretty obvious that the basis is $\begin {pmatrix}1& 0 \\ 0& -1 \end{pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix}0& 1 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix}0& 0 \\ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

My question is how do I calculate and show it ? what if it was an $n\times n$ matrix ?

Note: I can't use eigenvalues, Jordan, or inner product, this is for 'beginners' linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the basis in hand, you just have to prove its linear independence and span. LI here is trivial, and to show span you can essentially use what you already have: $tr(A) = 0$ if and only if it can be written in the form $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & -a\end{array}\right)$$This can be shown simply by taking the trace of an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix.

For the general case of $n \times n$ matrices, consider that $A_{nn} = - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} A_{ii}$. In the $3 \times 3$ case, we can take $$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{array}\right)\right\}$$ along with matrices which form a basis for the subspace with all diagonal entries zero. How can one generalize that to $n \times n$?

Comment: It doesn't have to necessarily be $A_{nn} = - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} A_{ii} $ right ? And for $n\times n$ it would be $(n-1)$ diagonal bases, and then there's $n^2-n$ vectors for all the other entries not in the diagonal and it's done with induction probably.

Comment: $tr(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ii} = 0 \implies A_{nn} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} A_{ii} = 0 \implies A_{nn} = -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{ii}$. And yes, so $dim \{A \in M_{n\times n}(f) | tr(A) = 0\} = n^2-1$.

Answer (score 2):

You've basically solved it! Since every matrix in $w$ is of the form
$$
\begin {pmatrix}a& b \\ c& -a \end{pmatrix}
=
a\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}+
b\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+
c\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
it is clear that 
$$
\beta=
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
spans $w$. Now you need only check that $\beta$ is linearly independent. Can you do this?

Comment: Oh yeah that's what I forgot. It just seemed like I'm making shortcuts. In order to show it in general we either take the determinant or multiply each vector by a scalar: $\alpha v_1+ \beta v_2+... =0$ and if it's clear that the scalars are equal to zero then it is linearly independent.